# Use selection to find values in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I couldn't quite figure this out:

I have two tables; Table one is named EthnicGroup; This table has the Country code, Name of the Ethnic and Percentage of this Ethnic stored.

In my second table named Country i have the following stored:
Name (the name of the country), Code (the code of that country), and some other stuff but that's irrelevant to this question

With the following query I select the Country codes from the EthnicGroup table that are having more than 7 different Ethnicities in their countries.

```
SELECT 
    country
FROM
    EthnicGroup
GROUP BY country
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 7)
ORDER BY country
```

I get the following Table by using This code:

### Country

EAK,
EAU, IR, SK

I now need to find out what countries correspond to these country codes by selecting the countries corresponding with these country codes.
I tried a few different things, like using a select command before using the above select command:

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    Country
WHERE(
SELECT 
    country
FROM
    EthnicGroup
GROUP BY country
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 7)
ORDER BY country)
```

I am almost certain I am very close to the answer. I would be grateful if anyone could help me a little with finding the solution

Comment: I found it out myself, thanks anyway guys!

Comment: `WHERE country IN (...` ?

Answer (score 0):

For such a selection, you need a condition in the `where` clause.  A subquery is not (really) a condition.  MySQL does accept a subquery; if it returns a value of 0 then it is false, a non-zero value is true.

For your purposes, `in` is the appropriate logical operator:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Country
WHERE code IN (SELECT country
               FROM EthnicGroup
               GROUP BY country
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 7
              );
```

Also note that the `IN` subquery does not need (and should not have) an `ORDER BY` clause.